# Input placemark or if not match a foo string

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I'm having a file like:

```
tata toto
tata titi
tata
```

If I'm making a regex like:
`^(tata) (toto)?`

I would like that if toto is found \2=toto, otherwise \2=foo

So I would like to have in output:

```
tata toto
tata foo
tata foo
```

Is that possible with regex?

Comment: regew with ansible, so python

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is to replace anything that is not `tata` followed by `toto` with `tata foo`:

```
import re;

string = '''
tata toto
tata titi
tata
'''

print (re.sub('^tata(?! toto$).*$', 'tata foo', string, 0, re.M))
```

Output:

```
tata toto
tata foo
tata foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `re.findall` and loop through to do anything that you like:

```
import re

string = '''
tata toto
tata titi
tata
'''

expression = r'^(tata) ?(toto)?'

output = ''
for pair in re.findall(expression, string, re.M):
    if pair[1] == '':
        output += pair[0] + ' foo\n'
    else:
        output += pair[0] + ' ' + pair[1] + '\n'

print(output)
```

#### Output

```
tata toto
tata foo
tata foo
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oJnZnf/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/oJnZnf/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---